# Apache Jmeter : Post an object not working with ModelAttribute

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc, jmeter

I am working on stress testing our webapplication written in Spring-MVC.

I would like to send an object `Person` to the application. I have added a system out to get the email, but whenever I am sending the object, it is null. What am I doing wrong?

Server code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/person/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addPerson(@ModelAttribute("person") Person person, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

            String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
            System.out.println("String is "+json);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.out.println("Person add called"+person.getUsername());
        person.setUsername(this.stripHTML(person.getUsername()));
        int personId = this.personService.addPerson(person);
        if (!(personId == 0)) {
            Person person1 = this.personService.getPersonById(personId);
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            Authentication authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(person1, null, authorities);
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
            return "redirect:/canvaslisting";
        } else {
            return "redirect:/";
        }
    }
```

Object sent  in body data :

```
{"person":{"id":0,"username":"testemail@gmail.com","firstName":"test","cleanCacheFlag":false,"googleDrive":false,"dropbox":false,"evernoteConsumed":false,"statusChangeTimeStamp":null,"useCalendar":false,"newsletterFlag":false,"tourSteps":null,"profession":null,"notiz":null,"telePhone":null,"lastVisitedBoards":null,"leftGroup":null,"optionalEmail":null,"facebookLink":null,"xingLink":null,"linkedinLink":null,"lastOnlineTimestamp":null,"userRole":null,"homePage":null,"excelImportQuota":0,"toEmail":null,"code":null,"authorities":null,"role":null,"newpassword":null,"token":null,"profilePhotoString":null,"accountNonExpired":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"active":true,"enabled":false}
}
```

Output :

```
Person add callednull
```

Screenshot :[image]

*Sample result*

```
Thread Name: Thread Group 2-5
Sample Start: 2017-06-29 15:17:11 IST
Load time: 6
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 6
Size in bytes: 237
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 205
Body size in bytes: 32
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 1
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 415
Response message: Unsupported Media Type

Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1048
Date: Thu, 29 Jun 2017 09:47:11 GMT
Connection: close


HTTPSampleResult fields:
ContentType: text/html;charset=utf-8
DataEncoding: utf-8
```

Request:

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/person/add/

POST data:
{"person":{"id":0,"username":"testemail@gmail.com","firstName":"test","cleanCacheFlag":false,"googleDrive":false,"dropbox":false,"evernoteConsumed":false,"statusChangeTimeStamp":null,"useCalendar":false,"newsletterFlag":false,"tourSteps":null,"profession":null,"notiz":null,"telePhone":null,"lastVisitedBoards":null,"leftGroup":null,"optionalEmail":null,"facebookLink":null,"xingLink":null,"linkedinLink":null,"lastOnlineTimestamp":null,"userRole":null,"homePage":null,"excelImportQuota":0,"toEmail":null,"code":null,"authorities":null,"role":null,"newpassword":null,"token":null,"profilePhotoString":null,"accountNonExpired":true,"credentialsNonExpired":true,"accountNonLocked":true,"active":true,"enabled":false}
}

[no cookies]

Request Headers:
Connection: close
Content-Length: 717
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change header Content-Type in HTTP Header Manager from:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

To:

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: where do you want me to add this? In Jmeter, in http header manager?

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you just have an @RequestBody annotation on person ?

```
public String addPerson(@RequestBody Person person);
```

Comment: Still no luck. HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a typo or copy-paste issue in your JMeter request

[image: JMeter request issue]

Also your JMeter configuration might be missing [HTTP Header Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-http-header-manager) configured to send [Content-Type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type) header with the value of `application/json`

Comment: Tried Person, person, p. All of them